# How to get path of node labels from a hierarchical table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I'm storing hierarchical folder information in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table using the [hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) type introduced in SQL Server 2008.

I have a table that has the most basic tree structure :
Folder[IdPath,FolderId,Label]

IdPath is of hierarchyid type, FolderId is int and Label is nvarchar(255)

The following query :

```
SELECT IdPath.ToString() AS LogicalPath,*
FROM Folders
```

Gives the following result:

```
|LogicalPath|IdPath|FolderId|Label       |
+-----------+------+---------------------+
|/          |0x    |NULL    |Root        |
+-----------+------+---------------------+
|/1/        |0x58  |1       |Folder1     |
+-----------+------+---------------------+
|/1/1/      |0x5AC0|2       |Folder1.1   |
+-----------+------+---------------------+
|etc...                                  |
+-----------+------+---------------------+
```

I'd like to get the full path of a folder of a given id. But instead of having the path of id's, Id'k like to get the path of the node labels associated to those ids.

For example, say I want to get that for FolderId=2, it would look like this:

```
    '/Root/Folder1/Folder1.1'
```

How would you do that in SQL Server 2008 ?

Are there any built-in functions to infer such an output from the IdPath ?